# Blank Screen after logging in locally after RDP to Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, blank-screen

Several users work from home once a day. They RDP to their workstations (running Windows 7) from home and then when they arrive in the office the next day, they login locally again.

When they login locally, they type their passwords and then the screen goes black. They can't lock or ctrl-alt-delete either.

Anyone else seen this?

Comment: is it possible for them to restart the workstation instead of only logging off (whole @ home), might solve the problem. But i have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: This could be a graphic card issue (resolution issue)... Are you users logging off or disconnecting?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this sounds like a video problem, but you can try to find the root cause. To root cause the issue, I would set up a VM on a Hyper-V host with the exact same configuration as the OS that the users have (I assume they all have the same OS). If possible, get a VHD with the same configuration.

Then, I would set up the Hyper-V host / VM for kernel debugging - see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2011/12/30/configuring-a-hyper-v-vm-for-kernel-debugging.aspx (though you might need to update some of the info on that page since you didn't specify the OS). Then, try to replicate the scenario - have any of the users log in to that machine (from home), logout / disconnect and then try to login from the Hyper-V console. If nothing happens, it's most likely a hardware / driver problem (not sure how you can debug those). If you do hit a kernel / user break, most likely a service such as `termsrv` is at fault and you can take it up with Microsoft from there.

If it is a hardware problem, try to see if your video card manufacturer has some newer/beta drivers for your OS/hardware configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is caused by an underlying process on the remote host. For a similar issue faced by me while connecting to remote host (running Debian OS) using mstsc program from my Windows 7, I used the following steps for resolution:

- Login to the remote host's terminal using putty
- Execute the following command on the remote host
  pskill -u  -9 #kills user processes
- The established connection with the remote host breaks after successful excution of this command
- Login again to the remote host using mstsc / GUI. Your desktop should be back.